# CloudFormation Optional Map Property - DeadLetterQueue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I need DeadLetterQueue property in 'AWS::Serverless::Function' to be created only if Env=ppd or Env=prod

```yaml
Conditions:
  IsPpdOrPrdEnv: !Or [!Equals [!Ref "Env", ppd], !Equals [!Ref "Env", prod]]
<...>
Resources:
  <...>
  TestFunction:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Sub '${Env}-Test-Function'
      DeadLetterQueue: 
        TargetArn: !If [IsPpdOrPrdEnv, !Ref TestSNSTopic, !Ref "AWS::NoValue"]
        Type: !If [IsPpdOrPrdEnv, SNS, !Ref "AWS::NoValue"]
  <...>
```

The error:

> Transform AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31 failed with: Internal transform failure.

I also tried:

```yaml
     DeadLetterQueue: 
        !If
          - IsPpdOrPrdEnv
          - 
            TargetArn: !Ref TestSNSTopic
            Type: SNS
          - !Ref "AWS::NoValue"
```

The error:

> Transform AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31 failed with: Invalid Serverless Application Specification document. Number of errors found: 1. Resource with id [TestFunction] is invalid. 'DeadLetterQueue' requires Type and TargetArn properties to be specified.

Any advise, please?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be **bug/limitation** of the SAM. There are open issues ([here](https://github.com/aws/serverless-application-model/issues/1435) and [here](https://github.com/aws/serverless-application-model/issues/1566)) in github which describe what you are experiencing.

Since both issues are open, they are **not resolved**. The only workaround provided is:

> We ended up needing to add a (manual or scripted) pre-deploy step that just removes the entire [DeadLetterQueue] config part if a [DeadLetterQueue] isn't desired.